# Como impedir que uma div com display flex encolha os elementos filhos?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Eu fiz o seguinte código de exemplo:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.div1 {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #0f0;
}

.div2 {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">150px</div>
  <div class="div2">150px</div>
</div>
```

Observe que tenho uma div "container" com 200px de largura e dentro outras duas divs com 150px de largura e preciso que tenha uma barra de scroll na div container.
Acontece que mesmo definindo a largura de 150px para a "div1" e "div2", as divs "encolheram" para caber em 200px conforme na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como impedir que isso aconteça?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após fazer a pergunta continuei a fazer alguns testes e consegui resolver o "problema".

Basta definir a propriedade [`flex-shrink: 0;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) nos elementos filhos:

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f00;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.div1{
    width:150px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.div2{
    width:150px;
    background-color: #00f;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">150px</div>
    <div class="div2">150px</div>
</div>
```

Feito isso obtive o resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vou deixar registrado aqui a solução caso mais alguém tenha a mesma duvida.

Answer (score 2):

Tentou usar o `min-width` para ambas as `div`s? Isso impede que as `div`s diminuam abaixo do limite e ocasiona o *scroll* horizontal.

Veja abaixo:

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f00;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.div1{
    min-width:150px;
    background-color: #0f0;
}
.div2{
    min-width:150px;
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">150px</div>
    <div class="div2">150px</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu continuei testando e consegui resolver usando flex-shrink: 0; nos elementos filhos, mas agradeço pela sugestão também!